# Do all controls have an id in html?

Tags: javascript, html

For the sampled case:
Does the DOM create an implicit ID to each input object? If so, how can I access this ID?

TIA, here is the code you've requested:

```
<html>
<script>
    function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var newcell = row.insertCell(0);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML;
    }
</script>

<body>
    <INPUT type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" `enter code here` />
    <TABLE id="dataTable" border="1">
        <TR>
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="txt[]" />
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No. there's no "automatic" IDs on dom elements. Only the ids you specify yourself via `id="..."` will exist. There will probably be some internal identifiers produced by the specific DOM engine being used, but those are internal-only and NOT accessible from the JS level, because those are the underlying C/C++ level, e.g. memory pointers.

Comment: **No**, the DOM does not create anything or add attributes, you have to do that yourself

Comment: Note that your "addRow" could be significantly simpler: `var table = document.getElementById(tableID); table.appendChild(table.children[0].cloneNode(true));`

Answer (score 0):

No, id's are assigned by you and you alone.

You could use something like JQuery to implicitily find elements.

```
$("input").each(function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

This more specific use of Id 
http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/
 
also add class to your Jquery elements
http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/